# Excel Automation Workbooks.Open() function throws Catastropic Error when app is called via Windows Service

Tags: c++, excel, windows-services

One of my application is about automating MS Excel while creating some drawing files. I am using basic tli method to achive that. **The code which has been running without any problem on xp machine has started giving the problem when I started working on windows7** to do some modifications on to it.What happens is as described below:

The code lines causing problem is around follwing:

```
if(!app.CreateDispatch("Excel.Application"))
{
    fprintf(log, "%s\n", "Microsoft excel, could not be launched. Please make sure it is installed on the target machine.");
    return;
}
else
{
    //Make the application visible and give the user control of
    //Microsoft Excel.
    ////    app.put_Visible(TRUE);
    ////    app.put_UserControl(TRUE);
    CString Title;
    CString  s = app.get_Version();
    //Excel 2003 takes 13 arguments hence we need to prepare options variant 
    COleVariant
        covTrue((short)TRUE),
        covFalse((short)FALSE),
        covOptional((long)DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);

    CWorkbooks b=app.get_Workbooks();

    CWorkbook bkThis, bkMaster;

    try
    {
        bkThis=b.Open(strFileName, 
            covOptional,  // UpdateLinks, 
            covOptional,  // ReadOnly, 
            covOptional,  // Format, 
            covOptional,  // Password, 
            covOptional,  // WriteResPassword, 
            covTrue,  // IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, 
            covOptional,  // Origin, 
            covOptional,  // Delimiter, 
            covOptional,  // Editable, 
            covOptional,  // Notify, 
            covOptional,  // Converter, 
            covOptional,  // AddToMru, 
            covOptional,  // Local, 
            covOptional  // CorruptLoad, 
            );

    }
    catch(CException *e)
    {
        fprintf(log, "The input file being tried: %s\n", strFileName);

        fprintf(log, "%s(%d): OLE Execption caught: SCODE = %x",__FILE__, __LINE__, COleException::Process(e));
        e->Delete();
        app.Quit();
        app.DetachDispatch();
        app.ReleaseDispatch();
        return;
    }
```

- When I run the code via Visual studio it runs fine but when I use a Windows service to launch this, the Workbooks.Open() function is failing with the 8000FFFF Catastrpic Error.
- The security privileges should not be problem as my ADO database connections are going through fine before calls to this code.

Please suggest if someone has any ideas on this.

Regards
YK

Comment: *when I use a Windows service* http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Comment: This problem is *probably* related to [session 0 isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463353), a change that was made in Windows Vista for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers guys, I appriciate that. Seems like I will have to do some workaround now.

Comment: Hello guys, is there any sample code available for xls automation using msxml or openXML in vc++ for server kind applications? I tried but couldnt find it on google when I search for that. openXML they describe on msdn only hints about c# and vb.

Comment: Hello Guys, I have been struggling with this issue since 15th Mar12, but ulitmately I have found a solution for this. You need to have a folder available in the windows 7 machine such as "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop", depending upon the machine you use. If it is 32 bit then modify accordingly. It will solve the problem. Thanks to a profile called "CSharper66" on internet.